# Populate alias DB from a bash script

Tags: linux, shell-script

My script `startalias.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
alias ls='ls -al --color=auto'
```

When I run this script my alias database does not pick it up.
But if I write it directly in the shell it works.
why?

Comment: If I copy that into my shell I get three error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alias` is a shell builtin. Executed in a subshell (like in a script) does not affect the main shell.